# protoc-gen-go does not execute on linux machine

Tags: go, grpc

I have installed `protoc-gen-go` and its in the bin direct and I have set the path to this as well.  The problem is that when I run `protoc-gen-go` from the commandline it does not error, but nothing happens as well.

If I run the following command  `sudo protoc --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative     --go-grpc_ths=source_relative     helloworld/helloworld.proto` I get the following error

```
protoc-gen-go: program not found or is not executable
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
--go_out: protoc-gen-go: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

However `protoc-gen-go` is available in my `/home/usrname/go/bin` path and this bin path has been exported to my linux PATH variable.  Not sure what is going wrong here.  The `protoc-gen-go` has the following permissions

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 usrname  9003065 Apr 16 11:16 protoc-gen-go
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are running `protoc` via `sudo`?  (it should not need superuser rights). I'd guess the path `protoc-gen-go` is in it not in root's path (run `sudo printenv PATH` to check).

Comment: thanks for this, this comment helped me figure out the problem.  I'm new to linux so I didn't know that sudo has a different path.  This made me go to protoc and grant `x` permission for the current user (me).  Now it seems to work.

Comment: That is a good solution; generally you want to avoid `sudo` except where it's really needed (some administrative task which requires elevated authentication).